# React vs React.js vs ReactXP

Tags: reactjs, reactxp

Are `React`, `React.js` and `ReactXP` the same thing and if not, how do they differ?

I keep reading some articles and I am confused about these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React and ReactJS are often used interchangeably. ReactXP is a library (or new app starter template) from Microsoft that uses React and React Native to allow for multi platform development. It supports development for iOS, Android and Windows 10 (partially) by using React Native and Web by using React.